# SpinnerNumberModel with short values

Tags: java, short, jspinner

I've created JSpinner with SpinnerNumberModel this way:

```
public class SpinnerFrameDoesntWork extends JFrame {
    public SpinnerFrameDoesntWork () {
        super("Spinner doesnt work");
        setSize(400, 200);
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void init() {
        final SpinnerNumberModel countSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel();
        final JSpinner countSpinner = new JSpinner(countSpinnerModel);
        countSpinnerModel.setValue((short)6);
        countSpinnerModel.setMinimum((short)6);
        countSpinnerModel.setMaximum((short)12);
        countSpinnerModel.setStepSize((short)1);
        add(countSpinner);
    }
}
```

I've noticed, that although spinner is displayed correctly, it doesn't allow to change it's value, it is stack on "6"

While troubleshooting, I noticed, that these two below work correctly:

With ints instead of shorts:

```
public class SpinnerDoesWork1 extends JFrame {
    public SpinnerDoesWork1 () {
        super("Spinner does work 1");
        setSize(400, 200);
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void init() {
        final SpinnerNumberModel countSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel();
        final JSpinner countSpinner = new JSpinner(countSpinnerModel);
        countSpinnerModel.setValue(6);
        countSpinnerModel.setMinimum(6);
        countSpinnerModel.setMaximum(12);
        countSpinnerModel.setStepSize(1);
        add(countSpinner);
    }
}
```

With changed object initialization order:

```
public class SpinnerDoesWork2 extends JFrame {
    public SpinnerDoesWork2 () {
        super("Spinner does work 2");
        setSize(400, 200);
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void init() {
        final SpinnerNumberModel countSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel();
        countSpinnerModel.setValue((short)6);
        countSpinnerModel.setMinimum((short)6);
        countSpinnerModel.setMaximum((short)12);
        countSpinnerModel.setStepSize((short)1);
        final JSpinner countSpinner = new JSpinner(countSpinnerModel);
        add(countSpinner);
    }
}
```

I managed to make it work, but I don't get what's wrong with first example? Why doesn't it work correctly as well?

Thanks for any help!